# disable drag and drop on fixed columns in gxt

Tags: gwt, gxt

i have a that grid consists of 3 columns. The first and third columns have fixed width but the middle is auto fit. What i want is to disable drag and drop on fixed columns so their positions in grid wont change ... any help for this ???

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the column to be fixed on the ColumnConfig using columnName.setFixed(true)